# Transition from UIViewController to Another

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, ios8

I am developing an app that has multiple views. How can I transition from one viewController to another.
I am going from "ViewController" which has story board, to "Question1ViewController" which has a xib file. Also can the code be in Objective-c (I'm still learning swift :=))
Thanks

Comment: You would normally create your second scene in the same storyboard as your first and link them with a segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transition between view controllers by using:

```
#import  "Question1ViewController.h"
//together with all the other imports
```

then in the place where you want to display the view controller if you have a navigation controller:

```
Question1ViewController *vc = [[Question1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Question1ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

If you do not have a navigation controller then use:

```
Question1ViewController *vc = [[Question1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Question1ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. There was just a minor error in your code, you write initWithNibName twice, but thanks a million for the rest of it.

Answer (score 3):

There are an almost limitless number of ways to do what you're asking.

Since you're fairly new at this, it would probably be better if you used a single way of storying your view controllers - Storyboards **or** xib files, but not both.

Each has it's quirks, and attempting to learn to use both at the same time means you have to learn 2 different ways of doing things at the same time.

First you need to decide what kind of transition you want.

The easiest thing is probably to put a navigation controller in your Storyboard, and then create your new view controller with a call to `initWithNibName:bundle:`, and then push it onto the navigation controller using direct calls to the navigation controller method `pushViewController:animated:`. (You can't use storyboard methods to invoke view controllers that aren't stored in a storyboard.)